# Push Spark Dataframe to Janusgraph for Spark running in EMR

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, gremlin, amazon-emr, janusgraph

I have an Janusgraph running on EC2 Instance and for its backend storage i have Cassandra cluster on EC2 as well. I want to push the aggregated and filter data to Janusgraph from python code Apache Spark(pyspark) running on Amazon EMR.

**What i have searched yet:**

I have read to insert using gremlin [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/insertDataGremlin.html), but is defines to do it for single vertex and edges. I want it to be inserted at once, may be like pushing all dataframe to Janusgraph.

Is there any efficent way to bulk insert directly from spark without converting it to CSV or any intermediate step of executing commands from bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spend around two weeks to find answer, posting it so it can help someone.

For writing the Dataframe running on remote computer, you can use `gremlin`, but for reading efficiently(in case you want to add edges) you may need `SparkGraphComputer`. Since my use case was only of insertion mainly. I will focus on it for now

If you want to start from scratch by making graph traversal and configuration, follow long answer/installations

## Short Answer(Insertion of vertex/edge from spark and querying janus from remote)

You need to have gremlin installed (`sudo pip install gremlinpython`)  at remote and you can insert edges like this

**1)Basic gremline imports and making remote graph object**

```
    from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
    from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
    from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
    from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
    graph = Graph()
    myGraphTraversal = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://<Your IP of JANUS>:8182/gremlin','myGraphTraversal'))
```

**2)For vertex**

```
    for row in df.rdd.collect():
         myGraphTraversal.addV('Country').property('name',row["name"]).next()
```

**3)For edges**

```
for row in df.rdd.collect():

        node_from = myGraphTraversal.V().has('country',"name",row["from_country_name"]).next
        wallet_to = myGraphTraversal.V().has('country',"name",row["to_country_name"]).next()
       myGraphTraversal.V(wallet_to).as_('t').V(wallet_from).addE("sends").to("t").property('value',row["value"]).toList()
```

**test vertex count from remote(imports and graph object similar as before)**

```
    print(myGraphTraversal.V().count().next())
```

=> 11800

## Long Answer/ Configurations:

Here i assume that your datastore and janus are at separate instance, but i have given hint of todos for local, if they are not

On janus-server-node,  install jars for python gremlin and tinkerpop

```
cd janus*    
./bin/gremlin-server.sh -i org.apache.tinkerpop gremlin-python 3.4.0(or 3.2.9)
```

First edit/create configuration file(janusgraph.properties) for connecting to gremlin.

```
sudo vim janusgraph.properties
```

write these configurations (note gremlin.graph and graph.graphname)

```
storage.backend = cql (whatever you bakend is)
storage.hostname = 192.xx.xx.XXX (DataStore/CASSANDRA NODE/NODE2 IP)
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.ConfiguredGraphFactory
graph.graphname=ConfigurationManagementGraph
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

backup the default Gremlin Server configuration

```
cp conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml.orig
```

make the ConfiguredGraphFactory configuration the default

```
cp conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server-configuration.yaml conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml
```

Now edit conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml

```
sudo vim conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml
```

make this changes (set host,remove anything from files array []

```
host: 0.0.0.0 
port: 8182 (8182 is default, and you should have this but for me I have 6182)
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {files: []}}}}
```

Run gremlin-server

```
bin/gremlin-server.sh # it should say that it is up on node 8182
```

Edit the conf/remote.yaml and define your janusgraph ip(you can also let it go with 127.0.0.1 if you are acceding gremlin console from same machine)

```
sudo vim conf/remote.yaml
```

change host port as

```
hosts: [192.xx.xx.xx] # your Janus node IP
port: 8182
```

open grmelin console

```
bin/gremlin.sh
```

Connect to remote (local in this case) 8182 port

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
```

next, divert all comands to your janusgraph running at :8154

```
:remote console
```

create graph,

```
gremlin> map = new HashMap();
gremlin> map.put("storage.backend", "cql");
gremlin> map.put("storage.hostname", "192.xx.xx.xx(IP of storage backend)");
gremlin> map.put("graph.graphname", "graph1");
gremlin> ConfiguredGraphFactory.createConfiguration(new MapConfiguration(map));
==>null
```

Not close the gremlin and also shutdown server(as you wish or as follow)

```
ps -ef | grep gremlin-python
sudo kill -9 <gremlin process id 1> <gremlin process id 2> <gremlin process id n>
```

edit script/empty-sample.groovy make graph1 as traversal source

```
def globals = [:]
myGraph = ConfiguredGraphFactory.open("graph1")
globals = [myGraphTraversal : myGraph.traversal()]
```

edit again conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml

```
sudo vim conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml
```

make this changes and add groovy to script to files for enabelling access to traversal from remote

```
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {files: [scripts/empty-sample.groovy]}}
```

re-run gremlin server

```
bin/gremlin-server.sh
```

**Now, from the remote pc from where you want to connect to the janus.**

Install gremlin python

```
sudo yum -y install python-pip
pip install gremlinpython
```

Go to `step 1 of short answer`(gremlin imports and graph object)

remote test vertex

```
print(myGraphTraversal.V().count().next())
```

=> 11800

**For EMR**

Put this in you bootstrap, so that gremlin can be installed before your spark  script step executes

```
sudo pip-3.6 install gremlinpython #pip install gremlinpython for python2
```